Undefined refenrece after importing static library in C
I have a static library built from another project and I want to use it in new project.
My CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(smah)
add_library(lotrlib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lotrlib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libdmggameserver.a)
set_target_properties(lotrlib PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /home/plomba/dmg/dmglib/gtgameserver)
add_executable(smah main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(smah lotrlib)

install(TARGETS smah RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

and my main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include "onetorulethemall.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const double inputValue = std::stod(argv[1]);
    
    std::cout << inputValue << std::endl;
    serveDarkLordMelkor();    
    return 0;
}


The directory '/home/plomba/dmg/dmglib/gtgameserver' does contain onetorulethemall.h file and this file does declare function 'serveDarkLordMelkor()'
But when I try to build this I get
/home/plomba/projects/smah/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `serveDarkLordMelkor()

also I see
#include "onetorulethemall.h"
in red in my IDE saying that file was not found and serveDarkLordMelkor is not suggested in autocompletion when I start typing it

the header file has nothing to do with the linker process. Your library isnt linked properly

what is the correct way to link it then? every resource on the internet says this is the right way

what does your link command say?

I didnt write any link command. I was expecting CMake to handle this. where can I see it?

it should be visible before your error message

[ 50%] Linking CXX executable smah
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/smah.dir/main.cpp.o: in function main': /home/plomba/projects/smah/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to serveDarkLordMelkor()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/smah.dir/build.make:98: smah] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/smah.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2

Probably, your library (libdmggameserver.a) doesn't define given symbol. You could check that with nm <path/to/libdmggameserver.a | grep serveDarkLordMelkor.

Hmm.... if you only show C++ code and this is, as requested in some answer  a  mixinb C/C++ code, why don't you tag it C++ and tag it only C?

The problem was in mixing C and C++ code. The included libdmggameserver.a is written in C and so its header had to be wrapped in

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...header file content...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

